# 'bool' object has no attribute 'idKey' using while

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a graphic application that gives a word after I press a key in my electric piano using a database.
I'm using PyGame, Tkinter and Sqlite.

The application is pretty simple and is almost finished,
but I'm stuck with that error between my piano.py and the frontEnd.py.

The thing is that I want a Label that writes what was the last key I pressed and put it on a canvas.

I know the problem is related to the 'while True' and already changed it with 'while idKey < 176' but with this change I receive the "noneType" error.

This is the current code in my file piano.py

**piano.py**

```py
import pygame
import pygame.midi
from pygame.locals import *


class backPiano():
    def funcPiano(self):
        self = backPiano
        pygame.init()


        pygame.fastevent.init()
        event_get = pygame.fastevent.get
        event_post = pygame.fastevent.post

        pygame.midi.init()

        input_id = pygame.midi.get_default_input_id()

        i = pygame.midi.Input( input_id )


        while True:
            events = event_get()

            if i.poll():
                midi_events = i.read(10)
                idKey = midi_events[0][0][0]

                if idKey == 176:
                    return False
```

And the code in my frontEnd (only the function with the problem):

**frontEnd.py**

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, font
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

from database import dictionary, path

from piano import backPiano

class frontEnd(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.backPiano = backPiano()

        def capturePiano(self):
                backPiano.funcPiano(self)
                superPiano = StringVar()
                superPiano.set(backPiano.funcPiano(self).idKey)
                labelPiano.configure(textvariable=superPiano)
                self.parent.update()


        canvasWidth = 500
        canvasHeight = 500
        w = Canvas(parent, width=canvasWidth, height=canvasHeight)
        w.place(x=monitorWidth/2,y=monitorHeight/2, anchor=CENTER)
        w.create_image(canvasWidth/2, canvasHeight/2, image=img, anchor=CENTER)


        labelPiano = Label(parent)
        labelPiano.place(x=monitorWidth/2,y=monitorHeight/2)
```

In the line **'superPiano.set(backPiano.funcPiano(self).idKey)'** I tried:

**"superPiano.set(backPiano.idKey)"**

But because the variable is inside a function it can't be called with that.

The exact error I have is this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\python\frontEnd.py", line 202, in <lambda>
    command=lambda : capturePiano(self)).place(x=monitorWidth/9,y=monitorHeight/2,anchor=CENTER)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\python\frontEnd.py", line 187, in capturePiano
    superPiano.set(backPiano.funcPiano(self).idKey)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'idKey'
```

I can't upload all the code, but the error is in the While True but removing it destroys all my code because I need the loop.

Thank you very much (and sorry if I made grammar mistakes).

Comment: `idKey` is local variable, not class variable so  you can't get it using `backPiano.idKey` or `backPiano.funcPiano(self).idKey`. You have to use `self.idKey`. OR you would have to use `return idKey` in `funcPiano()` and then you can get this value using only `backPiano.funcPiano(self)` - without `.idKey`.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says: `funcPiano` is returning a boolean (`True`) so when you try to take the `idKey` it fails, because booleans don't have that.